# Microsoft Graph API: 403 Forbidden error when trying to retrieve teams member on tenant

Tags: c#, bots, microsoft-graph-teams

I am facing the 403 Forbidden error while using TeamsInfo in Bot Application (.Net Core 6.0), getting Forbidden "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'".

Permissions:

`"Directory.AccessAsUser.All"     "Directory.Read.All"     "TeamMember.Read.All"     "User.Read.All"`

Trying to get Teams Member Information using user id. Do I required to add any other permission to get it or any Nuget change required?

I have created a BOT application using .Net Core 6.0. Trying to fetch teams member information like name, email and Team Member Id.

Using graph I am able to get name & email information but to fetch Team Member Id, I am trying TeamsInfo class (Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams) Nuget version 4.16.1.0

I am expecting Team Member Id using this call but getting forbidden.`